# Returns HTML for a new row

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**Question** : I have to dynamically display the cell ,and each row must have 3 cell  . I want to find how many rows it needed and if user enters 7 the first two row display 3 cell each and third row will only display 1 cell.

code:

```
var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var cell = '<td>' + cells[0].innerHTML + '<td>';
//console.log(cell);

document.getElementById('searchBtn').onclick = search;
var NUMPERROW = 3;

function search(){

    var num = document.getElementById('searchTxt').value; 

    //Loop Once per Row.
    var htmlStr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < num ; i = i + NUMPERROW){
        //htmlStr += '<tr>' + cell + cell + cell + '<tr>';
        if(num - i >= NUMPERROW){
            htmlStr += newRow(NUMPERROW);
        }else{// less than 3 to display
            htmlStr += newRow(num - i);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('thumbnails').innerHTML = htmlStr;

}
/*
 * Returns the html for a new row.
 * numToAdd: the number of cells to add for this row.
*/

function newRow(cellsToAdd){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can get the number of cells you need to add by using

```
newRow = NUMPERROW - (num % NUMPERROW)
```

where % is the modulo operator:  7 % 3 is the reminder of 7 / 3, which is 1